# como cambiar de color los iconos de la barra de notificaciones en android

Tags: android-studio

Quiero cambiar el color de los iconos de las notificaciones de la barra de estado y no se cual propiedad cambia el color.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Debió colocar un `status bar` que corresponda a un móvil android :), [Android Status Bar  icons color](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30075827/8933039) quizás le sirva, además de estos otros enlaces: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33316668/8933039 y https://stackoverflow.com/a/46132111/8933039 Y por ultimo este: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22192691/8933039

Comment: gracias, pero no me sirvio, lo pude resolver dandole un fondo mas oscuro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si usas sistema operativo o posterior, los guidelines de desarrollo dicen:

[**Colores: Los iconos de notificación de colores deben ser completamente blancos. Además, el sistema puede reducir y / o oscurecer los iconos.**](http://www.androiddocs.com/design/style/iconography.html)

Tu puedes aplicar un color o tinte pero este no afectara el color del icono.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En cambio únicamente puedes modificar el color del icono cuando se expande la notificación, esto mediante el método [**setColor()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setColor(int)).

Ejemplo:

```
    int color = 0x00FF00;
    NotificationCompat.Builder nb = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
            nb.setContentTitle(getString(R.string.title))
            .setContentText(getString(R.string.content))
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_androide)
            .setLargeIcon(bitmap_image)
            .setColor(color)   /* define Color */
            .setTicker("Hai Romania!")
            .setStyle(style)
            .build();
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: **CP 103 Cuando se califique con -1, es bueno para el sitio se indique la razón**, esto para mejorar la pregunta, eliminarla o si existen argumentos platicar sobre el tema.

Comment: muchas gracias jorge por la respuesta, al final se cambio el xml y no fue necesario implementarlo. No fui yo quien te califico como negativo. te di +5. saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Requiere min API 23

```
<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
```

Comment: Pero esto es para la barra de status y no específicamente para los iconos como se señala en la pregunta.